# Function error: Function doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: vb.net

I am new to programming and obviously not very experienced with writing functions. I wrote the function below, but as I get to the end, the End Function statements has an error: Function "viewSheets" doesn't return a value on all code paths.

I have researched the issue, but to no avail.  Here is my first try at a function:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module sheetView

Function viewSheets(sheetName As String, status As Boolean, show As String) As String

    Dim ThisApplication As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
    Dim WB As Excel._Workbook
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet

    WB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
    WS = DirectCast(WB.Sheets("sheetName"), Excel.Worksheet)

    With ThisApplication

        .ScreenUpdating = False

        WS.Select()

        .ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = status
        .ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = status
        .ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = status
        .DisplayFormulaBar = status
        .DisplayStatusBar = status
        .ExecuteExcel4Macro("Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", show )")


        .ScreenUpdating = True


    End With

End Function
```

End Module

Comment: Actually if you are not going to returning a value from your function, I would just make it a subroutine(method) which does not require a return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did declare a function, which by definition must return a value.

In VB you have to assign the function name or since VB.Net you can return using the return statement:

Before the End Function just put:

```
    viewSheets=""
```

You should read more about Functions and Sub routines in VB.

[Difference between Private Sub, Function and Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059537/difference-between-private-sub-function-and-class)

Comment: Use the `Return` statement in VB.NET instead of assigning a value to the function's name: `Return ""`

Answer (score 2):

It's declared as a function that returns a string. Because you have Option Strict turned on, you are required to have a Return statement on all code paths. The Return needs to return a string.

Comment: Actually, are you sure it's not just a warning? It's not because of Option Strict as I just found out, but my answer still applies.

Comment: what if it is just a warning ?

Comment: If it's just a warning, it means that you have at least one code path in the function which does not `Return` a value. If that code is hit, the function will return a null value (`Nothing`). That is, `FunctionThatDoesNotReturn() is Nothing` will be `True`.